# TikZ forest - Align extra contents added on the right of the final nodes

Tags: tikz-trees, forest

To explain "probabilistic" tree, I would like to add extra texts. I would like to align vertically all this extra texts. Is it feasible?

Is it also possible to have perfect baseline alignment between node and its extra content?

Does the package `forest` give easy to use names to the nodes of the tree?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}

\forestset{
  extra/.style={
    edge label={
      node [xshift=1.5cm] {$\leftarrow$ #1}
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree = {%
    sn edges,
    grow'  = 0,
    anchor = parent,
  },
  [
    [A
      [B, extra=b]
      [C, extra=c]
    ]
    [D
      [E, extra=e]
      [F
        [G, extra=g]
        [H, extra=h]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it would be helpful to have a handrawn sketch of the desired output

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329404/tikz-forest-decorations-and-alignment

Comment: In my previous post the tree is symetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer in the right direction -- instead of `extra style` a `write me style` is defined taking the forest tree as in a `bounding box`--the inward pointing arrows can (later) be modified to cater for the the length  from `tagZ` to `nodeB`  from--

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398722/197451

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}

\forestset{
  extra/.style={
    edge label={
      node [xshift=1.5cm] {$\leftarrow$ #1}
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree = {%
    sn edges,
    grow'  = 0,
    anchor = parent,
  },
write me/.style={
    tikz+={
        \node [anchor=mid west, red] at (.mid -| write me coord) {$\leftarrow$ #1};
    },
},
tikz+={
    \coordinate (write me coord) at (current bounding box.east);
}
  [
    [A
      [B, write me=tag Z]
      [C, extra=c]
    ]
    [D
      [E, extra=e]
      [F
        [G, extra=g]
        [H, write me=tag T]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and the explanation.