# TikZ forest - Align content using a macro and not a style

Tags: formatting, forest

In [this previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/554855/6880), **js bibra** gives me a way to align contents by using some styles. I need indeed to work with a macro like in the following MN(ot)WE.

I'm trying to adapt the use of `\coordinate (write me coord) at (current bounding box.east);` of the solution of **js bibra** but the way I do things change the bounding box at each use of my macro. Maybe an overlay could do the job...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}

\newcommand\comment[2]{
    \node [anchor=mid west, xshift=.75cm] at (#1.mid -| current bounding box.east)) {#2};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    for tree = {%
      sn edges,
      grow'  = 0,
      anchor = parent,
    }
    [
        [$A$
            [$B$, name = nB]
            [$C$, name = nC]
        ]
        [$D$, name = nD]
    ]
    \comment{nB}{Node B}
    \comment{nC}{Node C}
    \comment{nD}{Node D}
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved by adding back coordinate `write me coord`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}

\newcommand\comment[2]{
    % use node "write me coord"
    \node [anchor=mid west, xshift=.75cm] at (#1.mid -| write me coord) {#2};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    for tree = {%
      sn edges,
      grow'  = 0,
      anchor = parent,
    },
    % define coordinate "write me coord"
    tikz+={
      \coordinate (write me coord) at (current bounding box.east);
    }
    [,use as bounding box
        [$A$
            [$B$, name = nB]
            [$C$, name = nC]
        ]
        [$D$, name = nD]
    ]
    \comment{nB}{Node B}
    \comment{nC}{Node C}
    \comment{nD}{Node D}
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @projetmbc The rectangular node `current bounding box` groups after each `\comment`, since the anchor is at `mid west` and the right half is always out side of `current bounding box`. But as far as being saved in another coordinate/node `write me coord`, position of that node is static. In short, `current bounding box` is a special node (that updates its position).

Comment: Yes I guessed this. Thanks also for this coment.